# Some Android devices extremely slow when rendering canvas elements

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, canvas

Im developing an app for android devices, and found that samsung galaxy S4 specifically, has extremely poor performance when app/web page uses canvas. 
Odd thing is, that its not always the case.

I have tested 2 sample apps.

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/FishIETank/Default.html

and

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/TouchEffects/Default.html

the first one works fine, and outperforms my Nokia (which is dual core) and is expected. However, the other demo, is almost completely unresponsive and framerate is close to 1, where as all other devices render it fine.

Since the first app runs well and the other one doesnt, it beggs the question, why ?
First one has no event listeners, where as the other one has touch listeners. Could touchmove be the cause instead of canvas...or is that demo using some canvas features that the other one isnt, and thus has poor performance.

I have read lots of topics about this issue, and none seem to have answer. Most are many months old...so i thought ill make a new topic.

Is there any way to solve the canvas issue on Samsung S4 ... and potentially other android devices running 4.2.x. 
If any StackOverflow users here has S4, can you test both demos and confirm my observations?

Comment: FWIW, Samsung Tab 2 and Samsung Note 3 both get destroyed on the dots, are fine on the fish tank.

Comment: Trying this out on my S4.

Comment: Trying this out on my S4.  First link, Fish Tank, maxed out at 60 FPS with 20 fish, with 1000 fish it's at 8 FPS.  Second link, visibly slow in portrait mode, faster in landscape.  How can you get the FPS on the second link?

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping to test.

There is no fps counter on the second one. I copied it over to my server and edited its source to add fps counter.
http://www.migrainepal.com/cordova_app/touch_demo/

i have a hunch that its around 15fps, which is ok...and means that event handling is not the cause of S4 slow performance.

The actual app im developing, and that is having problems is here:
http://www.migrainepal.com/cordova_app/index.html#/
on browser and other devices it works fast, on S4...its very laggy :(
Click drag the chart and points.
In the end it will be packaged using cordova.

Comment: On my Note 3 the fps for the dots hovers around 12 - 13

Comment: the performance depends on the Android Version, the phone firmware (different firmwares like CyanoGen, SlimSaberKat, Samsung Stock, Google Play Version... use different configurations for the GPU) and of course the browser used (Chrome / AOSP) . Check out `chrome://gpu` if you are using chrome browser to see if you are using accelerated HW canvas.

Comment: @rupps is right, and I suspect he's not on Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is not a Canvas specific issue, but a `requestAnimationFrame` issue. The first animation does not attempt to use `requestAnimationFrame`, but the second does, in [this file](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/TouchEffects/Demo.js) on `line 206`.

Android Browser on firmwares <= 4.2 *does not support* `requestAnimationFrame`, and instead uses `setTimeout`, dividing one second by specified frame rate in Hz, which executes renders in the normal event loop.

`setTimeout` does not execute at the exact time in milliseconds requested, but enqueues the event in the loop at the time specified. If the event loop is hung by other javascript on the page, or the single-core device decides something else is more important, the runtime is *very* vulnerable to de-prioritization without the `requestAnimationFrame` API, and the callbacks enqueued using `setTimeout` will stutter and bunch. [More on `setTimeout` resolution and timing](http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth).

Unfortunately, you are at the mercy of the event queue if you are (1) going with this Canvas-based approach and (2) on a platform that does not support `requestAnimationFrame`. [Here is the reference table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe) for what browsers support the feature.

Cheers!